# Excel dropdown to entire column

Tags: excel, validation, excel-formula, drop-down-menu, copy

How to copy a dropdown menu (data validation) to entire column in Excel (only rows that having something else too). And, in this case, how to leave row for the header?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer and now it's working:

```vb
Sub pasteCellToColumn()
    Dim lastRow As Long, i As Long

    lastRow = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("hiddenData").Range("A1").Copy

    For i = 1 To lastRow
        If Len(Trim(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i).Value)) <> 0 Then
        Sheets("Sheet1").Range("K" & i).PasteSpecial _
        Paste:=xlPasteValidation
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Inspired from your answer. Actually you can do it without VBA: Copy the cell. Select a range. Right-click then Paste Special... . Select Validation. Done.

Answer (score 5):

Instead of clicking in a cell, click on the header (A,B,C, etc) and go to: Data Tools > Data validation.

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

1. Select the entire column you want to validate
2. Click on "Data Validation" from the Data tab

   [image]
3. Choose "List" from the "Allow" box

   [image]
4. Click on the arrow to the right of the "Source" box and select the cells containing the allowed values

   [image]

And you are good to go!

More on that [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-data-validation-to-cells-29fecbcc-d1b9-42c1-9d76-eff3ce5f7249).

Answer (score 1):

To copy and paste only the dropdown list (validation), and only to not empty cells, do the following:

1. Select every possible cell (including empty ones) where you want to have the dropdown menu pasted.
2. Hit <kbd>F5</kbd>, then <kbd>Special...</kbd>, finally <kbd>Constants</kbd> radio button and <kbd>OK</kbd>. This will select only cells which are not empty from your previous selection.
3. Home > Paste > Paste Special...
4. <kbd>Validation</kbd> radio button and lastly <kbd>OK</kbd>.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is not working for me because in this case the column (where I want to paste validation) is empty and there are values in other columns. So I want paste as long as there is cells having any data in same row. I should maybe use some vba?

Comment: I am confused. Column or row? Where do you need the validation? Can you upload an image?