# return entire column syntax, based on drop down box

Tags: excel

Part of a complex formula that I am using refers to an entire column, (D:D). But I would like to be able to select that column based on a drop down box. So for instance if the drop down box has 3 choices, choice1 would input A:A into my formula, choice2 would input B:B into my formula and so on. 
Any thoughts on how to do that? Thanks!

Comment: Perhaps related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29059999/1531971

Comment: Use a cell reference in place of where you want the columns to be in your formula, then add data validation to that cell and have users change it there.

Comment: I guess I need some clarification. Could you give me an example of how to use the cell reference?

Comment: This is my formula : =IF(ROWS($1:1)>COUNTIF(D$2:D$5000,"<>"),"",INDEX(D:D,SMALL(IF(D$2:D$5000<>"",ROW(D$2:D$5000)),ROWS($1:1))))                                                                                                                            I would like the D:D part to change dynamically based on what has been selected in the drop down box